# Difference between times in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a temporary table in the database that contains:

```
 userid | time              
--------|---------------------
 1      | 13-01-24 00:04:01 
 1      | 13-01-24 00:04:04 
 1      | 13-01-24 00:05:06 
 2      | 13-01-24 00:06:06 
 2      | 13-01-24 00:06:08
```

I would like to get an answer as follows:

```
1,  0 second
1,  3 second
1,  62 second
2,  60 second
2,  2 second
```

I've tried 'TIMEDIFF' scripts (`max(time)`, `min(time)`), but it does not output what I want.  Please help, I'm using PHP.

Comment: I think you should decide the language you are going to write in, you started in english and went off somewhere else.

Comment: "I've tried scripts TIMEDIFF (max (time), min (time)) does not match the script turned out just as I want, what's the solution, please help! I'm using php" (Indonesian)

Comment: Don't just say I have this and I want this. Please specify what you really want as output ( with details that how is your sample output produced ). We're not magicians.

Comment: @Miro It's pretty obvious that the output is the difference in times between each successive records.

Comment: @Barmar Thx.. Got it. seems that I should've guessed the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL solution:

```
SET @prev_time = null;
SELECT userid, IFNULL(timediff(`time`,@prev_time), 0) diff,
       @prev_time := `time`
FROM mytable
ORDER BY time
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a85a/7)

Comment: thank's MR. Barmar, but i'm confused, that answer are sql's scripts, how are convert that answer in php? i tried in php as follow: $prev_waktu= null;
$count1 = mysql_query ("SELECT IFNULL(timediff('waktu','$prev_waktu'), 0) as selisih , '$prev_waktu' := 'waktu' FROM mdl_temporer_log2");
while($jumlah1 = mysql_fetch_array($count1)){
$jumlah1_ = $jumlah1['selisih'];}. but that script is error

Comment: Please don't post long code in comments, it's very hard to read. Update your question if necessary. There's a PHP solution in Miro Markarian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Solution:

(The same @Barmar 's solution but in php)

```
<?php
$timearray = array("13-01-24 00:04:01", "13-01-24 00:04:04", "13-01-24 00:05:06", "13-01-24 00:06:06", "13-01-24 00:06:08");
$prevtimestamp = null;
foreach($timearray as $it) {
    $datetime = explode(" ", $it);
    $date = explode("-", $datetime[0]);
    $time = explode(":", $datetime[1]);
    $newtimestamp = mktime($time[0], $time[1], $time[2], $date[1], $date[0], $date[2]);
    if($prevtimestamp == null) $prevtimestamp = $newtimestamp;
    echo $newtimestamp - $prevtimestamp . " seconds";
    $prevtimestamp = $newtimestamp;
}
?>
```